# How do I make x server start up without connected screen?

Tags: linux, xserver

I'm running a RHEL 5 server and I want it to start up the X server without the the screen connected. The first reason is that I want to connect a screen to it once in a while to configure it manually. And secondly I want to have VNC server start up, which it does not do now without the X server. All I really want is to not be forced to have a screen connected for the server to start up normally...

Right now the X server will not start during boot and the log in `/var/log/Xorg.0.log` reads:

```
[...loads of stuff...]
(WW) NV(0): No outputs definitely connected, trying again...
(II) NV(0): Output VGA1 disconnected
(II) NV(0): Output DVI0 disconnected
(II) NV(0): Output VGA0 disconnected
(II) NV(0): Output DVI1 disconnected
(WW) NV(0): Unable to find initial modes
(EE) NV(0): No valid initial configuration found
(II) UnloadModule: "nv"
(II) UnloadModule: "ddc"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libddc.so
(II) UnloadModule: "i2c"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libi2c.so
(II) UnloadModule: "int10"
(II) Unloading /usr/lib64/xorg/modules/libint10.so
(EE) Screen(s) found, but none have a usable configuration.

Fatal server error:
no screens found
```

Can I somehow save the settings that X server loads when the system boots with the screen connected? Or do I have to configure the settings manually? Or is there a better way?

Comment: Not programming-related - try http://superuser.com ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Xvnc](http://www.realvnc.com/products/free/4.1/man/Xvnc.html) instead of your regular X server.

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Using VNC satisfied my needs.